# Changing or editings Keys in objects, in order to show in view. Using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

Example JSON:

```
[{"name":"John", "date_of_birth":"01/12/1987","marital_status": "Open Relationship"}]
```

Example view:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th> Name </th>
   <th>Date of Birth</th> 
  <th>Martial Status</th>
 </tr>

 <tr ng-repeat= "profile in profiles">
  <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.date_of_birth}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.marital_status}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to ng-repeat the keys or table heading too. I know how to put ng-repeat and get keys and values. But what I will like is to change the keys and make them look nice, for e.g  : date_of_birth should be Date of Birth, but with ng-repeat on it.

Comment: I think this is a wrong approach; even if it were possible, you would have only one language ( English ). The label is not a "Model problem"

Comment: Offtopic, but I could not help it:) "martial" should be "marital". PS: I agree with @Max, that this is wrong approach.

Comment: I saw this feature in ng-grid , using gridOtions to define columns. I was thinking may be I can use something in vanilla angular

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the comments in under your question that it is not the best approach. Also, remember that in reality you shouldn't count on a particular order when iterating over object's params (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210).

***However*** ;) in the spirit of solving interesting question…

If you really want to do this, you can do it this way:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in profiles[0]">
   <th>{{ key | snailToHuman }}</th>
 </tr>

 <tr ng-repeat= "profile in profiles">
  <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.date_of_birth}}</td>
  <td>{{profile.martial_status}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And create a filter `snailToHuman`, e.g.:

```
app.filter('snailToHuman', function () {
  return function (snail) {
    return snail.split('_').map(function (word) {
      word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }).join(' ');
  };
})
```